# laravel photos not showing properly

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a laravel program that displays photos, it is suppose to display them all in a grid but thats not happpening they are all over the place here is the code for displaying the images

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  @if(count($albums)>0)
    <?php
    $colcount = count($albums);
    $i = 1;
    ?>
  <div id='albums'>
    <div class="row text-center">
      @foreach($albums as $album)
        @if($i == $colcount)
          <div class="medium-8 colums end">
            <a href="../public/albums/{{$album->id}}">
              <img class="thumbnail" src="storage/album_covers/{{$album->cover_image}}"alt={{$album->name}}">
              <br>
              <h6>{{$album->name}}</h6>
         @else
           <div class="medium-8 colums">
            <a href="../public/albums/{{$album->id}}">
              <img class="thumbnail" src="storage/album_covers/{{$album->cover_image}}"alt={{$album->name}}">
              <br>
              <h6>{{$album->name}}</h6>
          @endif
         @if($i % 4 == 0)
         </div</div><div class="row text-center">
         @else
           </div>
         @endif
          @endif
       <?php $i ++ ?>
   @endforeach
   </div>
   </div>
 @else
  <p>No Albums to Display</p>
@endif

@endsection
```

My understanding of this code is, it should display 4 rows of 8 images. I have checked this code many time and I can't find what is wrong.
Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: try add to your `img` tag class called `img-fluid` from bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

> The `storage/app/public` directory may be used to store user-generated files, such as profile avatars, that should be publicly accessible. You should create a symbolic link at  `public/storage` which points to this directory. You may create the link using the `php artisan storage:link` command.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure#the-storage-directory

Once that is done, and have made sure that the file is present in the storage directory, you may use the [`asset`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset) function to link to the file.

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" 
    src="{{ asset('storage/album_covers/' . $album->cover_image) }}"
    alt="{{ $album->name }}">
```

Comment: Thanks linktoahref

Comment: I have already made the artisan  stroage:link works fine, the images are in thumbnail form its just that they do not display properly using the above code

Comment: You might need to check your html structure as it seem to have incomplete div tag and it seems there is an extra `@endif`. Also replace the `thumbnail` class with `img-thumbnail`